# event.preventDefault() only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-11

When I press the tab button the first time, it works and tab is prevented, however if i press it again straight away, the default is not prevented, and I tab out of the inputbox.

If I type something then tab then type something else then tab, then it is default is prevented everytime

The problem is I can't tab twice in a row. Any idea what might be the problem?

```
 $("#functionSearch").on("change propertychange keyup",function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event)
    if (event.which == 9 ) {
        console.log("TAB")
    }else{
        clearHighlight();
        var input = $(this).val();
        if(input.length > 0){
            filteredArr = jQuery.grep(linksArr, function( val, index ) {
                return ( val.toLowerCase().indexOf(input.toLowerCase()) != -1);
            });
            selectElements(filteredArr);
        }
    }

});

// MAY BE USEFUL
function selectElements(filteredArr){
    $(filteredArr).each(function( index, link){
       var id = link.split("~")[1]
       $("#"+id).addClass("selected");
    });
    highlightFirstElement();
    }

    function highlightFirstElement(){
        $(".selected").first().addClass("highlighted");
    }

    function highlightNextElement(){
        $(".selected").next().addClass("highlighted");
    }

    function clearHighlight(){
        $(".highlighted").removeClass("highlighted");
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");
    }

<div id="functionSearchDiv" class="funSearch">
    <input type="text" id="functionSearch"></input>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create a CodePen or JSFiddle for this?

Comment: Are you replacing your `#functionSearch` elements by some other code?

Comment: @RobertAKARobin jsfiddle doesn't even prevent it once so im trying code pen https://jsfiddle.net/6n0qfqt4/

Comment: @AniketSahrawat no its not being replaced

Comment: This is a little confusing, you can't prevent the TAB key from actually moving the focus ?

Comment: @adeneo i can prevent it, but only once. the second time I press tab, it is not prevented

Comment: @AniketSahrawat that's not true, jQuery is normalized cross browser

Comment: Sure doesn't work for me -> https://jsfiddle.net/71k052jy/

Comment: @AniketSahrawat `event.returnValue = false` doesn't work at all. maybe it's because IE11

Comment: Why would you want to prevent tabbing in the first place? Takes away user familiarity

Answer (score 2):

By the time `keyup` is fired, the TAB key may have already done its job of displacing the focus to another element, meaning that the `keyup` event will be fired on that other element instead of being fired on the input field.

The simplest solution is to listen to `keydown` instead of `keyup` (see [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shawn/5e536jtq/1/)).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things going on. You are using keyup, when you press tab, by the tab you call `event.preventDefault()` the focus has already moved to the next element. 
Next, you have propertychange and change listener, same thing as before. In addition when you press tab twice the second time there is no change as the property did not change the second time! You must use keydown instead of keyup and check the order your events are being fired!